# Python Kubernetes MaxRetryError

Tags: python, kubernetes, kubernetes-python-client

I am trying to use Kubernetes in a django app in my PC (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) but after going through a lot of different errors I went and tried a simple example ([Deploy Pod from YAML file](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/examples/apply_from_single_file.py)) from the kubernetes python library. Even though the example is very straightforward I keep getting the same error:

```
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='192.168.139.242', port=6443): 
Max retries exceeded with /apis/apps/v1/namespaces/default/deployments 
(Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fef64215430>: 
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

My code looks like the example (I've only changed the yaml file):

```
from kubernetes import client,config,utils


def main():
    config.load_kube_config()
    k8s_client = client.ApiClient()
    yaml_file = 'video_capturer.yaml'
    utils.create_from_yaml(k8s_client,yaml_file,verbose=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And I get the previous error in the `create_from_yaml` function, the IP and port should be right.

If I try to do the equivalent in a new ubuntu terminal (`microk8s kubectl apply -f video_capturer.yaml`) it works perfectly fine.

Do you know what might be wrong with my k8s installation?

EDIT: After trying different approaches I have noticed that what works fine is using microk8s to deploy the pod, but when I simply use kubectl I get the following error:

```
~$ kubectl get all
The connection to the server 192.168.139.242:6443 was refused - 
did you specify the right host or port?
```

I think that something in my kubectl might be broken.